# Mac OS X Time Machine Restore - Failure?

Tags: boot, macbook, time-machine, restore

I've got an late 2009 macbook pro 13' and yesterday I replaced the native hd (new hd: Hitachi; same form factor).

I choosed "Restore from Time Machine" in the options menu on the snow leopard install discs and waited several hours to complete.

After an reboot the mac  shows up a white screen with apple logo and tiny loading animation. Nothing happens. After another restart; the same.

Now I cant boot from CD using the `C`-Key and I have no idea how to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I boot my Mac using `Shift`.

After that I installed Snow Leopard without restore. Then I migrate my user account, programs and other files by using the `Migration Tool`.

Everything works now.

Comment: You should also check out rsync. I was bitten once, or twice, by Time Machine and it's been smooth sailing since I started using rsync (requires a bit more setup, but well worth it)